# How to avoid using iloc or hard coding the index number pandas to dynamically fetch rows from single data frame into multiple subsets?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

My dataframe looks likes this

```
country1    state1  city1   District1
india   36  20  40
china   27  21  35
honkong 34  21  38
london  32  21  38
company technology  car brand   population
adf     java       Ford          40
ydfh    java      Hyundai        19
klyu    java      Nissan         47
hy6g    dotnet    Toyota         20
rghtr   dotnet    Hyundai        30
htryr   dotnet    hummer         12
```

I wanted to create a multiple subset from  single dataframe, I do not wanted to use index number or iloc function or hard coding the index number because it will filter out whenver there is new entry either after entry london or after last entry

If there is any new entry comes it should also needs to be captured, any clues how to perform in pandas or using numpy?
hope this question is clear

Comment: Your question is very vague. You ask if something can be done in pandas or numpy but don't say what that something is. You say you want to create "multiple subset" from a single dataframe but you didn't specify how those subsets should be created. Are they filtered by city, by car brand, by state ? As it stands, I am not sure your question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is saved as df you can use groupby and save the grouped sub-data to a dictionary for future reference.

```
d = {}
for group, frame in df.groupby('country1'):
    d[group] = frame
```

Also if you want to groupby multiply columns pass a list to groupby as follows

```
for group, frame in df.groupby(['country1', 'technology']):
    d[group] = frame
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, actual source data is not in proper shape, that is the issue, I figured out the solution